# Using jQuery to display hidden form elements if multiple options are selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, visibility, contact-form

I've got a drop-down selection in a contact form, and want to display a few additional form elements if either of options are selected. Otherwise, the additional elements should be hidden. I've been able to get this working with a single option, with the following code:

```
$(".hidden-section").hide();
$("#contact-form select").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "extra options trigger one") {
        $(".hidden-section").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $(".hidden-section").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get this to work if either of two options are selected. The only way I've been able to get the jQuery even working is this:

```
$(".hidden-section").hide();
$("#contact-form select").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "extra options trigger one") || ($(this).val() == "extra options trigger two") {
        $(".hidden-section").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $(".hidden-section").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

But in this case, the hidden elements will show up once any option other than the default is selected.

Any ideas on a better way to go about this? Would much appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us part of markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got extra parentheses on this line that shouldn't be there:

```
if ($(this).val() == "extra options trigger one") || ($(this).val() == "extra options trigger two") {
```

Should be:

```
if ($(this).val() == "extra options trigger one" || $(this).val() == "extra options trigger two") {
```

That is, the `if()` statement's condition needs to be entirely enclosed within the outer parentheses, so:

```
if (condition1 || condition2)          // valid
if ((condition1) || (condition2))      // valid
if (condition1) || (condition2)        // NOT valid
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I had to use the second valid option to get this to work, putting both conditions in parenthesis. It worked after that, though, so the final line was: if (($(this).val() == "extra options trigger one") || ($(this).val() == "extra options trigger two"))

Comment: You're welcome. I'm surprised you needed the inner parentheses though, it should work without them both in the sense of not being a syntax error and doing what you want (because `==` has a higher precedence than `||`).

Answer (score 0):

Let me add some comments on your code.

First - don't use `$(".hidden-section").hide();` - you should add `display:none` to the `.hidden-section` CSS. The reasons is that for some people the network connection is slow, and until their browser will run the javascript for `hide` it will take some time. During this time it will be visible. They will experience a flicker - something will appear and suddenly disappear.

Comment #2 -

If your HTML does not load in Ajax, you should wrap it with `$(function(){ /* code here */  });` - as this will run the JavaScript only when the entire page is ready. This is required when you JavaScript refers to HTML content.

Comment #3 -

Your code will be hard to maintain - imagine there's a third option that requires extra fields.

You are better off adding a class on each option that requires extra fields, for example `<option class="requires-extra">Option 2</option>` and then your JavaScript is shorter.

```
$(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        var $requiresExtra = $(this).find("option:selected").hasClass("requires-extra");
        if ( $requiresExtra ) {
            $(".hidden-section").slideDown("fast");
        } else {
            $(".hidden-section").slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yzPn/) for a working example.

Comment: Regarding your comments: (1) using `.hide()` rather than putting `display:none` in the CSS is useful if the page is designed to work for users who have disabled JavaScript in their browser (because then the controls only get hidden when there's a way to show them again). (2) You don't need document.ready if your script block is after the elements it manipulates, but OP doesn't have a problem in this area since the one-option code worked. (3) Good advice.

Comment: Cool. I hope it didn't come across as too critical: it was definitely intended as friendly _constructive_ criticism...